# XPath Multiple Nodes

Tags: xml, xpath, jasper-reports

I'm using Xpath 1.0 Expression to query an XML document.
My aim is to output all of the selected nodes into a Jaspersoft Report which displays a new page along with the corresponding data with every Uid.

Here's a snippet of my XML document to which I have simplified:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <modules>
        <Operation>
            <Operation>
                <wellUid lookupLabel="Well992454">cf1</wellUid>
            </Operation>
        </Operation>
        <RigInformation>
            <RigInformation>
                <rigName>RigName12345</rigName>
                <rigInformationUid>rig005</rigInformationUid>
                <rigManager lookupLabel="Manager554">554</rigManager>
            </RigInformation>
            <RigInformation>
                <rigName>RigName4578945</rigName>
                <rigInformationUid>rig001</rigInformationUid>
                <rigManager lookupLabel="Manager2254879">2254</rigManager>
            </RigInformation>
        </RigInformation>       
        <Well>
            <Well>
                <wellUid>cf1</wellUid>
                <wellName>Name 1</wellName>
            </Well>
            <Well>
                <wellUid>cf2</wellUid>
                <wellName>Name 2</wellName>
            </Well>
        </Well>
        <ReportDaily>
            <ReportDaily>
                <wellUid>cf1</wellUid>
                <rigInformationUid>rig001</rigInformationUid>
            </ReportDaily>
        </ReportDaily>
    </modules>
</root>
```

I'm trying to sort out an XPath expression that displays all the information under the wellUid. So if there is a wellUid "001" and a wellUid "002", then there should be only two rows returned with all the information from Well, RigInformation, Operation and ReportDaily.

RigInformation does not have a wellUid but does have a rigInformationUid to which ReportDaily also has.

Here is my queries I've tried so far...

```
//ReportDaily/ReportDaily[wellUid = //Well/Well/wellUid] | //RigInformation/RigInformation[wellUid = //Well/Well/wellUid] | //Operation/Operation[wellUid = //Well/Well/wellUid] | //Well/Well[wellUid]
```

and

```
//Well/Well[wellUid and //ReportDaily/ReportDaily[wellUid = //Well/Well/wellUid and //Operation/Operation[wellUid = //Well/Well/wellUid and //RigInformation/RigInformation[rigInformationUid = //ReportDaily/ReportDaily/rigInformationUid]]]]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started, given that you iterate over the given wellUid's:

```
root/modules/*/*[descendant::wellUid/text() = //Well/Well[1]/wellUid/text()] | 
root/modules/*/*[descendant::rigInformationUid/text() = //descendant::rigInformationUid[preceding-sibling::wellUid/text() = //Well/Well[1]/wellUid/text()]/text()]
```